# JavaScript and Multi-threading by browser for async operations?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, promise

I'm experimenting with laying out data in indexedDB object stores and using Promise.all to extract the data, build HTML, and add it to different sections of a tabbed display within a single-page web application.

If Promise.all is used to extract the data from different object stores or different key ranges of the same store and then build HTML fragments and insert them before resolving each individual promise, is the browser really performing these steps concurrently such that the process will complete quicker?

To be more specific, there is one promise for the extraction of data for each tab in the display.  If the transaction completes successfully then the data is passed to a function that builds and inserts the HTML and, when it returns, the promise resolves.  The promises for each tab are grouped in the Promise.all and, when that resolves, the program navigates to the first tab and displays it.

Is this really working on multiple things at the same time or is it just providing a timing method to show the first tab only after it is known that data and HTML for all tabs have been successfully gathered and built?

Is it accurate that this is quicker than chaining the promises to run one after the other with then statements but not faster than just kicking off each promise individually and placing a then on the first tab's promise to display it?

I know JS is a single-thread language but the documentation for some of these methods reads that "in a separate thread..."; so, I don't quite understand if the browser is performing things at the same time or not.

Thank you.

Comment: The browser will do http requests concurrently when triggered in a Promise.all situation, but js code will not (unless you are using web workers)

Comment: "*I know JS is a single-thread language*" this is oft-repeated and incorrect. JS can run multithreaded. It's a gross oversimplification/warping of the real explanation - code that a programmer writes will *usually* run in a single thread. That doesn't make JS itself single-threaded, though.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*just kicking off each promise individually and placing a then on the first tab's promise to display it?*". With `Promise.all`, you are just kicking off each task individually as well, but it allows you to wait until *all* results are back before displaying them.

Comment: "*the documentation for some of these methods reads that "in a separate thread...";*" - which documentation of what method in particular are you referring to? It might need fixing. Something returning a promise does not mean that it involves another thread.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not referring to the documentation of `promise` statements but the indexedDB methods, `get()` for example in MDN web docs.

Comment: @Bergi I meant that the promises weren't chained with `then` statements and waiting for the previous to complete before commencing. I understand what you mean about the array of promises in a `Promise.all` commencing individually as well.  I was trying to ask whether when dealing with database operations as described is there any real difference between all three methods apart from when the first tab is displayed.  Thank you.

Comment: @Gary Ah, yes, indexedDB will probably use multiple background threads to process the requests you send it. They don't surface to javascript though.

Comment: @Gary If you want to use Javascript outside the browser; node.js for instance, you can run things asynchronously.  I've done this in node.js and it's really great!  Look at the `async.js` library in npm.  Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but HTTP/2 ought to have this ability correct?

Comment: @leeand00 Thank you for the suggestion.  I haven't used node.js but have been reading about it.

Comment: @Gary It isn’t theory, it’s practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, let's just stipulate that there's no use of webWorker threads so we're just  talking about regular Javascript in a web page running in a browser.

In that case, there's only ONE thread of Javascript running at any given time and the whole system is event driven in a browser (more on that later).

So, when running actual Javascript code things can only run one at a time.  But, as soon as you make a function call that has a native-code backed non-blocking, asynchronous implementation, then the Javascript calls out to the native code, the asynchronous operation is initiated and then it immediately returns control back to the Javascript interpreter so more Javascript can run.  In this manner, you can start multiple asynchronous operations at once that will proceed independent of the Javascript interpreter.

How much independent they are and how parallel they are depends upon the implementation of those asynchronous operations.  If they are all accessing the same database, there may or may not be some real parallelism between database operations available - it all depends upon the database implementation.

Now, let's assume you did start multiple database operations and you are tracking when they a re all done with `Promise.all()`.  As each one finishes, it will insert an event in the JS event queue.  When the JS interpreter has nothing else to do, it will pull the next event from the event queue and run the callback associated with the completion of that asynchronous operation.  When using `Promise.all()`, that callback will (among other things), mark that single operation as done and store its result for later access.  When, all the operations you are tracking with `Promise.all()` have completed in this manner, then the promise that `Promise.all()` returns will resolve and you can get access to the array of results.

Now to your specific questions...

> If Promise.all is used to extract the data from different object stores or different key ranges of the same store and then build HTML fragments and insert them before resolving each individual promise, is the browser really performing these steps concurrently such that the process will complete quicker?

If each asynchronous operation is capable of efficient running in parallel with others (at the native code level), then "yes" the total time to completion will be faster if the operations are run in parallel, than if they are sequenced.

> Is this really working on multiple things at the same time or is it just providing a timing method to show the first tab only after it is known that data and HTML for all tabs have been successfully gathered and built?

That depends upon the specific asynchronous operations and if multiple of them can be run in parallel.  Usually, they can, but not always.

> Is it accurate that this is quicker than chaining the promises to run one after the other with then statements but not faster than just kicking off each promise individually and placing a then on the first tab's promise to display it?

Usually, yes.

> I know JS is a single-thread language but the documentation for some of these methods reads that "in a separate thread..."; so, I don't quite understand if the browser is performing things at the same time or not.

The browser runs your Javascript (the executing of actual Javascript instructions) as a single thread (ignoring webWorkers here) with no parallelism.  But, when you call an asynchronous operation, that operation has an implementation in native code and that native code behind it is free to use threads or other asynchronous, non-blocking OS APIs/tools to do its job.  That may allow parallelism between separate asynchronous calls, thus allowing multiple calls to proceed in parallel.

The `IndexedDB` interface contains many asynchronous interfaces which means it is event driven and must be running asynchronously with some native code behind it.  You would have to test a given implementation of that database in a given browser to see how well it parallelizes multiple requests in-flight at the same time.  Each browser implementation could have different characteristics.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Whether or not I can really determine what is truly taking place in terms of operations running in parallel, at least using `Promise.all` in this situation won't slow anything down.  Thus far, the individual promises in the array have been completing in array order; but that includes the time of building the HTML and not only the data retrieval.

Comment: @Gary - To know how much  benefit you were getting from attempting to run them in parallel, you'd have to benchmark parallel vs. serial in a specific browser and measure the difference.  If the underlying database uses a lot of central locks or doesn't use multiple threads, it might not gain much from attempting to run in parallel, but if it was well written for multiple requests, you could gain a lot by coding for parallel access.  In general, it's best to code for parallel access when practical.

Comment: You wrote *"But, when you call an asynchronous operation, …, free to use threads or other …. tools to do its job"*, but previously:
*"no use of webWorker threads so we're just talking about regular Javascript in a web page.

In that case, there's only ONE thread of Javascript running at any given time and the whole system is event driven"*

Comment: But ECMA specification clearly claims, that it is standard behavior, that using some async like actions can cause **host environment** to do parallelism, using multithreading over the OS via runtime machine.

Even though, talking about web workers as external api - they may only exist, because the language itself allowed so to be implemented in host environments, runtime agents can execute their scenarios simultaneously. See https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-agent-clusters

Comment: @GadzhievIslam - There are two separate things here.  One is a thread that your Javascript is running in.  The second is whatever the host implementation decides to do in order to implement various APIs that are surfaced to Javascript.  Those are separate things.  The first controls the parallelism of YOUR own Javascript execution.  The second can allow asynchronous APIs to "run in the background" using native code while your Javascript does something else.  Beyond that, I don't know what point you're trying to make.  Please note also that this is a 4 year old question too.

Comment: @GadzhievIslam - And webWorkers are yet another thing which the question was not asking about.  That's a specific way to run a separate thread of Javascript in its own mini-environment.

Comment: @jfriend00 Of course, my point was that even without web workers, would it be host environment neither browser nor node, JS itself is not, as you said: "ONE threaded", since 2010 already, that's why i posted specs link and mentioned everything else.

Comment: @GadzhievIslam - Yes, all threading discussions about Javascript have to do with the specific host environment.  That's why this question and answer are targeted at a specific host environment (the browser).  You seem to be not seeing that the browser or nodejs ARE the host environment.

Comment: @jfriend00, Disagree. I know about the context of this question and that the host env. here is the browser, but my point is still, that even though it is so, your answer contained straight forward statement: "there's only **ONE thread** of Javascript running at any given… **in browser**".

Which in my opinion is wrong from the beggining.

Comment: @GadzhievIslam - I still don't get what your beef is with this answer.  Ignoring webWorkers which my answer clear states is the context in which it is written, then there is only one thread that runs your Javascript in a browser.  There may be other threads used in the implementation of the JS engine and its APIs, but your actual Javascript runs in only one thread and thus you don't get threading concurrency issues with your own Javascript in a browser.  If you still think something in my answer is wrong, then please propose which phrase needs to be changed and what it should be change to.

Comment: @GadzhievIslam - Yes, if you use webWorkers, you can have more than one thread of Javascript (though the threads can only communicate in limited ways).  But, the question was not asking about a situation that used webWorkers so the VERY FIRST sentence of my answer states that I'm answering for a non-webWorker situation because that's the situation that was being asked about.  the important and relevant-to-the-question part of this answer is that `async` operations in Javascript do not make new threads of Javascript.  One thread of Javascript executing through the event loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 Alright, here's the thing. I'm talking about the situation without webWorkers too. I think you're wrong, thinking that JS is one-threaded itself, as most people do, because-it's not the point that some operations do not make "new threads of JS", but rather the fact that JS itself inside using agents in specific host env. can use whatever it wants number of threads to process things while execution.

When you speak about "threads of Javascript" (c) it's not accurate, since runtime decides on it's own how to process program in parallel, using or not multiple threads or agents.

Comment: @jfriend00, And one more thing, event loop take place when host env. needs work with events, taking just tasks out of task queue of it. But executing code on runtime machine asynchronous or in parallel is up to Execution Context Stack and runtime Agents. Which clearly may use as more threads or as it wants, because, again, JS (ECMA) specification allows it from the position of language standard, and browsers or any other hist envs. can do so and so, if we take a look deeper.

Comment: @GadzhievIslam - Perhaps we just don't understand each other.  Yes, a host implementation is free to use as many threads as it wants in implementing it's JS engine or natively coded APIs.  That has absolutely nothing at all to do with whether two pieces of Javascript can be running at the exact time in separate threads which is what this answer is about.  I don't think we're making any progress here and I'm heading out so I think we can be done here.

Comment: @GadzhievIslam - One more thing.  Browsers are not free to run normal Javascript (non webWorkers) in multiple simultaneously executing threads on their own because that would create threading conflicts between all shared variable access.  That would simply not work without the user's Javascript code running in each thread doing proper thread synchronization before accessing any variable that other threads can see (which is a complicated thing to do correctly).  That's why webWorkers have a completely separate execution environment and do not share variables.