# How does await/promise finish execution if control goes back to the parent?

Tags: javascript

I recently learned that when a statement is being awaited, i.e; the function is taking time to return a value, the control goes back to the parent function which does other tasks.

If this is a single thread and the parent does other tasks, when does the awaited function get time to finish its task?

Does the awaited function get some stipulated amount of time in every loop iteration?

Comment: BTW, am I the only one that promised not to use promises? Callbacks are more fun...

Comment: an `async` function returns a Promise - I believe when a Promise resolves, the callbacks (sorry if wording is incorrect here) are put on the microtask queue (which has a higher priority than the regular message queue) - so to use the result from an async function (the only place you can await, except top-level-await of course) you have to await the function or use the regular Promise `.then` methods where the result will be available in the callback to `.then`

Comment: @ITgoldman - Promises rely on callbacks ... `.then(x => dostuff())` - looks like a regular callback, right? because it is just a callback - so, using Promises, you'd be using callbacks

Comment: If the parent function doesn’t do anything to invoke the event loop then the child function won’t get a chance. So it’s important to make sure everything is cooperating at some point.

Comment: you mention *loop iteration* ... what loop? if you have a loop `while(true){}` then nothing else will run at all - but Promise/async/await is irrelevant if you have such code anyway - I think you need a basic understanding of what Promises are and how async/await work with promises to make arguably more readable code, absolutely no change to how javascript actually works though

Comment: Promises are often used for tasks that happen somewhere else, for example waiting for a response from an external server, or loading images, files, etc. The difference between callbacks and promises is that you don't have to pass a callback function to the external process and hope that they will execute it. The control now remains in your own code, the external process just tells you when it's finished and you can still decide what to do on your end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript and Multi-threading by browser for async operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58965757)

Comment: @Bravo I was thinking of the event loop

Comment: then you misunderstand the event loop